# How do I find the rows of two tables where a row element from TableA is different from TableB

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server.
I am trying to find the groups that a student is not part of. Table A is a list of all the groups in the database. Table B shows the groups that each student is apart of. When I try joining the two tables and then using WHERE to see the differences, it does not work. I think I have to use EXCEPT but I have no idea how to.

#### The goal

What I want to happen is have a query, for example studentA, and then it must return all the groups that studentA is NOT apart of. Therefore, for the example tables below it should return groupC because it is the only group that studentA is NOT apart of.

TableA:

| groupName | groupDescritpion | groupTags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| group A | doesnt matter | doesnt matter |
| group B | doesnt matter | doesnt matter |
| group C | doesnt matter | doesnt matter |

TableB:

| username | groupName |
| --- | --- |
| studentA | group A |
| studentA | group B |
| studentB | group B |
| studentB | group C |

### What I tried:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT TableA.groupName, TableA.groupDescription
  FROM TableA
  INNER JOIN TableB 
      ON TableA.groupName=TableB.groupName
  WHERE TableB.username != 'studentA';
```

### What should happen:

| username | groupName |
| --- | --- |
| studentA | group C |

Comment: studentB is not associated with group A - why did you leave that out? And your WHERE clause filters studentA OUT of the resultset while your resultset includes only studentA - can you clarify your goal and make it consistent with your sample data and your expected results?

Comment: @SMor Very Sorry. I meant to say i want to be able to get all the groups where a particular student is not part of. Therefore, for example, if I were querying student A, then it must only return the groups studentA is not apart, thus  group C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT T.USERNAME,A.groupName
 FROM TABLEB AS T
 CROSS JOIN TABLEA AS A
    EXCEPT
 SELECT X.USERNAME,X.GROUPNAME
 FROM TABLEB AS X
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, what is X though?

Comment: If, for example, I want to get he groups studentA is not part of, what do I do?

Comment: SELECT GROUPNAME FOR TABLEB WHERE USERNAME<>'STUDENTA'.  Something like this

Comment: what exactly? The first query or the second one? If the first one, then why studentB is omitted in groupA

Comment: The first one and it is because in the example I wanted to get he groups studentA is not apart of. if i were doing it for studentB, then it would return groupA

Comment: OK.Select a.groupName,a.groupDescritpion from tablea as a where not exists(select 1 from tableb as b where a.groupName=b.GroupName and b. username='StudentA')

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have been stuck on this for two whole days